# Python cp regex: copy an unknown dir

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Currently in a program I have, I use:

```
os.system('cp /run/user/1000/gvfs/*/store_00010001/DCIM/100ND610/* /home/$USER/Pictures/$(date +%F)/')
```

But I want to use shutil.copy to do the copying for me. I have one problem though. In Bash I can have a path that has a regex/wildcard like `*` or `?` eg.: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/*/store_000?0001/`, but how to I do that in python for a path?

I'm using Python 3.3

Answer (score 1):

The following is a clean way to use `glob` when you are expecting only one match:

```
import glob

unknown_dir = "/run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto*/"
matches = glob.glob(unknown_dir)

if len(matches) == 0:
    raise Exception('No matches')

if len(matches) > 1:
    raise Exception('Too many matches')

known_dir = matches[0]
```

If you are expecting zero or more matches, you can simply iterate over the list of matches and handle each one in turn:

```
import glob

unknown_dir = "/run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto*/"
for match in glob.glob(unknown_dir):
    # use match
```

Answer (score 0):

@eryksun answered my question with recommending glob. For future people looking at this question, here is how I used it:

```
import os
import glob

unkown_dir = "/run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto*/"
known_dir = str(glob.glob(unkown_dir)).strip("[]'")
```

I need the path as a string, hence me using str() and strip().

I'll now be able to use shutil.copy. Thank you @eryksun!

Comment: String-ifying a list and then stripping away the extra characters is not a good practice. It will be give you an empty string if there are no matches or a run-together mess if it happens to match multiple things. I've added an answer with safer code.